# On Rasiowa Sikorski lemma

Tags: set-theory

The [Rasiowa Sikorski lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasiowa%E2%80%93Sikorski_lemma):

Let $(P, \le)$ be a poset and $p \in P$. If $D$ is a countable family of dense subsets of $P$ then there exists a $D$-generic filter $F$ in $P$ such that $p \in F$.

Where does $F$ exists? by construction $F \subseteq P$ . But "in $P$" is "$F \in P$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a filter *in* $P$ (or, rather, *in* $\langle P , \leq \rangle$)  we mean a subset $F \subseteq P$ satisfying certain properties (if $p \leq q$ and $p \in F$ then $q \in F$; if $p , q \in F$ then there is an $r \in F$ with $r \leq p,q$).

Unfortunate terminology (especially when you leave out mention of the partial ordering), but I think we're stuck with it at this point.

Comment: It is not $F \in P$ you are saying? Only $\subseteq$?

Comment: What about $M$ is model of set theory. Then $P \in M$. But is also $F \in M$ by this theorem?

Comment: @dolan: Yes, a filter in $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ is only a subset of $P$.  The Rasiowa-Sikorski lemma says that under certain circumstances you can always construct (using ZFC) a filter in a partially ordered set satisfying additional properties.  This then reflects down to situations where $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ is an element of a model of (a good fragment of) ZFC (and $M \models \leq \text{ partially orders }P$), but still the filter will only be a subset of $P$ (which happens to belong to the model $M$).

Comment: It means $F$ not necessarily in $M$? OoO

Comment: @dolan: If $M$ is a model of ZFC and $\langle P , \leq \rangle , \mathcal{D} \in M$ are such that $M$ thinks that $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ is a poset and also that $\mathcal{D}$ is a countable family of dense subsets of $\langle P , \leq \rangle$, then by Rasiowa-Sikorski there will be an $F \in M$ such that $M \models F\text{ is a filter in }\langle P , \leq \rangle\text{ which is generic for }\mathcal{D}$.  (Usually $F$ will actually be a $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter in $\langle P , \leq \rangle$.)  [cont...]

Comment: [...inued]  But it could also be that $M$ is a _countable_ model of ZFC, and $\langle P , \leq \rangle \in M$ is a poset (and $M$ knows this).  Then since $M$ is countable there are only countably many dense subsets of $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ which belong to $M$, and we may enumerate them (outside of $M$) as $D_0, D_1 , \ldots$.  By Rasiowa-Sikorski there will be a filter $F$ in $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ generic for $\{ D_i : i < \omega \}$, however in almost every situation we will have $F \notin M$.  (This is an important point for forcing.)

Comment: Very interesting! If enumeration of $\mathcal D$ is in $M$ then also $F \in M$ but if enumeration of $\mathcal D$ is outside $M$ then possibly $F$ also not in $M$?

Comment: @dolan: More or less that's correct.  The first part is because $M$ models ZFC, and Rasiowa-Sikorski is a theorem of ZFC, so Rasiowa-Sikorski is also true in $M$  The second part there are some cases when it won't work out, but only because the partial order in question is "too simple".  If the partial order is "separative" (I won't go into the technical definition here) then any filter meeting each dense subset of $\langle P , \leq \rangle$ which belong to $M$ cannot be an element of $M$.

Answer (score 2):

The filter exists in the universe. That is to say that if $V$ is the universe of sets, $P$ is a countable poset and $D_n$ for $n\in\omega$ is a family of dense subsets of $P$, then there is some $F\in V$ which is $D$-generic.

This is often used in forcing, we take $M$ a countable transitive model of $\sf ZFC$, and we take a partial order $P\in M$, since $M$ is countable it only knows about countably many subsets of $P$. So the collection of "all the dense subsets of $P$" relative to $M$ is a countable collection.

Therefore in $V$ itself there is a $P$-generic filter. In the nontrivial case, this generic filter does not exist in $M$, and then we add it to create $M[G]$ which is another countable transitive model of $\sf ZFC$.